# Does anyone know how to map Microsoft's Instant Viewer mouse function to a keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, hardware

After reading [Jeff's review](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001221.html) of [Microsoft's Natural Ergonomic Keyboard 4000](http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/mouseandkeyboard/productdetails.aspx?pid=043). I decided to get one. It comes with this really nice Instant Viewer feature that it assigns to the middle button of your mouse. Not wanting to lose my middle button "open in new tab" function. I wanted to assign it to the keyboard. I'v looked at task manager when using it and it seems to be part of the ipoint.exe.

Does anyone know if its possible to assign it to the keyboard and how?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to do it using [Microsoft's keyboard software (IntelliType Pro) and mouse software (IntelliPoint)](http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/mouseandkeyboard/Download.mspx)?

Comment: The next thing to go after is http://www.autohotkey.com , remapping and macros for keyboard and mouse.

Answer (score 0):

I just installed Intellitype Pro 7.1 on XP (I didn't install Intellipoint) and it does let you assign Instant Viewer to a key. You might need a Microsoft keyboard to use it though (you need an M$ mouse for Intellipoint).